# Query that gets information from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am writing a bunch of queries that are getting information from multiple tables or actually uses sub queries to initialize them. The query that I am having trouble with right now actually is supposed to make another field thats not in either of the tables. The exact definition of the query that I am writing is as follows...

> List the country name, it’s population, and the sum of the populations of all cities in that country. Add a fourth field to your query that calculates the percent of urban population for each  country. (For the purposes of this example, assume that the sum of the populations of all cities  listed for a country represent that country’s entire urban population.) Order the results of this  query in increasing order of urban population percentage.

The code that I have tried for this query is as follows

```
SELECT name, population, SUM(population) FROM what.country JOIN what.city ON city.country_code = 
country.country_code GROUP BY population ASC
```

The tables that I am using are

```
               Table "what.country"
     Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
 continent       | continent             | not null
 region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
 surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
 indep_year      | smallint              | 
 population      | integer               | not null default 0

               Table "what.city"
    Column    |         Type          |                     Modifiers                  
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id           | integer               | not null default nextval('city_id_seq'::regclass)
 name         | character varying(35) | not null default ''::character varying
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 district     | character varying(20) | not null default ''::character varying
 population   | integer               | not null default 0
```

Comment: Feels like homework week @ stackoverflow ツ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26321846/905902 duplicate homework. September is late this year, so it seems.

Comment: Yeah, someone's running a badly taught class or doesn't have appropriate tutorial sessions in addition to the lectures. Ryan, homework is ok on stack overflow, but **say that it's homework** or an assignment please. I'll be downvoting and flagging if you continue to post without that.

Comment: You're doing CMP_SC 3380 at Missouri with @jimmy, right? "Lab 6"?

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the problem solved - the only thing missing is the percentage of urban population which you can achieve by dividing the sum of the urban population (which you've already calculated) by the total population:

```
SELECT   cnt.name AS country_name, 
         cnt.population AS total_population, 
         SUM(cty.population)/(cnt.population) * 100 AS urban_percentage
FROM     what.country cnt 
JOIN     what.city cty ON cty.country_code = cnt.country_code 
GROUP BY cnt.name 
ORDER BY 3 ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was confused about, You helped me out a lot!

Comment: @mureinik I actually get one error when I try this. This is the error Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ASC" LINE 6: GROUP BY cnt.name ASC ^ in

Comment: @ryan Yeah, that was a stupid mistake on my part. RADAR's edit should have fixed it - see now.